# Calling functions within prototype in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to learn extendable jQuery plugin development. I'm completely stumped on how to call functions within a class from the jQuery plugin wrapper.

I created the wrapper for my code mostly from [here](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/05/creating-highly-configurable-jquery-plugins/), and have tried to understand/use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149239/writing-jquery-plugins-using-classes-and-prototypes) but haven't had much luck.

The important bits of the code below. I'd like it so I can call (eg) `$(something).carousel(5)` and it passes that number to the `slide` function within the Carousel class. Same for strings, so `$(something).carousel('go')` would run `go` within the Class.

How can I do this with this structure?

```
(function(window, $){

  var Carousel = function(elem, options){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
  };

  Carousel.prototype = {

    defaults: {
     [...]
    },

    init: function() {
      this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
      this.create();
      return this;
    },
    create: function() {
       [...]
    },
    slide: function(num) {
       [...]
    }
  };

  Carousel.defaults = Carousel.prototype.defaults;

  $.fn.carousel = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {

      var carousel = new Carousel(this, options);
      if (!options || typeof options == 'object') carousel.init();
      else if (typeof options == 'number') carousel.slide(options);
      else if (typeof options == 'string') carousel.options;

    });
  };

  window.Carousel = Carousel;

})(window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're more or less on the right track, your main problem is that calling `carousel.options` will just access the `options` attribute of your `Carousel` instance. What you want to do is dynamically call the function on the instance:

```
 $.fn.carousel = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {

      var carousel = new Carousel(this, options);

      // do a loose comparison with null instead of !options; !0 == true
      if (options != null || typeof options === 'object')
        carousel.init();
      else if (typeof options === 'number')
        carousel.slide(options);
      // make sure options is the name of a function on carousel
      else if (typeof options === 'string' && typeof carousel[options] === 'function') {
        carousel[options](); // call the function by name
      }

    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @bokonic! That's got the functions going, but not the one where I'm trying to pass the number to the slide function with either `carousel.slide(options)` or `carousel.slide[options]()`. Any ideas?

Comment: you're missing a comma after the closing `}` in your definition of `create` (right before `slide`) in the Carousel prototype.

Comment: Eh that was a typo just when I pasted the code into the question, it's got the comma in the full thing.

Comment: not sure from the code you posted; try `console.log(carousel)` and see if the the prototype contains the `slide` method (seems like it doesn't); something is likely wrong with the function definition.

Comment: weird.. I did a console.log and `slide` was included in it. I copied the entire script as it currently is (incomplete) into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tommaitland/T9van/) if it'd help can set up the HTML too. I seem to be getting an error for both like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slide' of undefined` now, and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeClass' of undefined`